# Linking an XPages Tab Bar to a Document

Tags: mobile, xpages, tabbar

I have the following code (on my first attempt at a mobile app) in an XPage. I seen to have missed a step in linking the document to the tab bar. Unfortunately I have no access to safari books online at present (or would look up the Extension Library reference in there).

The code below does nothing. No error and does not updated the document viewed in the mobile device.

If I place the code on a button on the document directly - then it works.

Can anyone help?

CODE

```
<xe:tabBar id="tabBar1" barType="segmentedControl">

<xe:tabBarButton id="tabBarButton1" label="Accept">
<xp:eventHandler event="onClick" submit="true"
refreshMode="complete">
<xe:this.action>
<xp:actionGroup>
<xp:modifyField name="Status" value="1" var="document1"></xp:modifyField>

<xe:moveTo direction="Left to Right"
forceFullRefresh="true" saveDocument="true" transitionType="slide">
<xe:this.targetPage><![CDATA[#{javascript:if(viewScope.page == "allLive"){
    return "allLive";
    }else{
    return "viewPage";
    }}]]></xe:this.targetPage>
</xe:moveTo>
</xp:actionGroup>
</xe:this.action>
</xp:eventHandler>
</xe:tabBarButton>
</xe:tabBar>
```

Comment: I see a reference to a `document1` data source, but am not seeing where that data source is defined. I'm guessing that your tab bar is defined outside of the panel that the data source is attached to, which would explain the behavior, but you'll have to provide more context to be able to know the definitive cause.

Comment: Hi Tim, It was indeed the problem.

I moved the tabBar inside the panel and hey presto - solved! Thanks for your reply.

Graeme

Comment: Cool... I've added an answer so we can make it clear to others that this is a valid resolution. :)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the `tabBar` component is located within the same context (panel / Custom Control) as the target (e.g. `document1`) data source. Otherwise the `modifyField` action will not be able to access the referenced data object.